# Why is sendevent freezing?

Tags: python, adb

I have been working very hard to find how to emulate tap with sendevent to be able to use very precise swipes. I just succeed to make a tap using this code shared down below in stackoverflow.

Surprisingly, the tap is execute but just the "finger down" order....it stay like this untill i move my mouse over the emulator windows.

What Am I missing ??

```
from ppadb.client import Client


def lerp(p1: tuple, p2: tuple, points: int) -> list:
    '''
    Creates a list of points with len = points between p1 and p2 using lineal interpolation

    :param p1: First point.
    :param p2: Second point.
    :param points: Number of points in between.
    '''

    output = []
    header = [_p2 - _p1 for _p1, _p2 in zip(p1, p2)]
    for p in range(points + 1):
        percent = p / points
        output.append((p1[0] + percent * header[0], p1[1] + percent * header[1]))
    return output


class AdbInput:
    """
    Sends input events to a given adb device using ppadb and the sendevent shell command.
    """

    def __init__(self, client: Client, device: int = 0, eventId: int = 6):
        '''
        Creates an AdbInput object able to send inputs to an adb device
        :param client: The adb client.
        :param device: The index of the device (Default is 0)
        :param eventId: The event id. (Default is 2, change it if your device doesnt work)
        '''
        self.device = client.devices()[device]
        self.eventId = eventId

    def sendEvent(self, event: str):
        """
        Sends a raw adb event.
        :param event: The event. Composed by 3 DECIMAL numbers: Type Event Value
        """
        self.device.shell(f'sendevent /dev/input/event{self.eventId} {event}')

    def startTouch(self):
        """
        Starts a touch secuence
        (if you want to tap or swipe, use the functions \"tap\", \"swipe\" or \"smoothSwipe\")
        """

        self.sendEvent('1 330 1')  # BTN_TOUCH Down
        self.sendEvent('3 57 10')  # PRESSURE

    def setPosition(self, position: tuple):
        """
        Sends the POSITION_X and POSITION_Y events
        (if you want to tap or swipe, use the functions \"tap\" and \"swipe\")
        """

        self.sendEvent(f'3 53 {position[0]}')  # POSITION_X
        self.sendEvent(f'3 54 {position[1]}')  # POSITION_Y

    # Input functions
    def tap(self, position: tuple, duration: float = 0):
        """
        Taps the screen in the given location for a specific duration.
        :param position: The position to touch.
        :param duration: The duration of the tap.
        """

        # Start Tap
        self.startTouch()
        self.setPosition(position)
        self.sendEvent('0 0 0')  # SYN_REPORT
        self.device.shell(f'sleep {duration}')

        # End Tap
        self.sendEvent('1 330 0')  # BTN_TOUCH Up
        self.sendEvent('0 0 0')  # SYN_REPORT

    def swipe(self, positions: list):
        """
        Swipes in the screen going to the positions really fast
        :param positions: The points to reach
        """
        # Start the swipe
        self.startTouch()

        # Cycle through the positions
        for pos in positions:
            self.setPosition(pos)
            self.sendEvent('0 0 0')  # SYN_REPORT

        # End swipe
        self.sendEvent('1 330 0')  # BTN_TOUCH Up
        self.sendEvent('0 0 0')  # SYN_REPORT

    def smoothSwipe(self, positions: list, wait: float = 0, smoothness: int = 10):
        '''
        Swipes in the screen going to the positions \"smoothly\".

        :param positions: The points to reach.
        :param wait: The wait between touches (recomend using 0 or something really close)
        :param smoothness: The number of extra points added to each path to smooth it (Default = 10)
        '''

        # Get the needed points
        points = []
        for p in range(1, len(positions)):
            points += lerp(positions[p - 1], positions[p], smoothness)

        # Start swipe
        self.startTouch()

        # Cylce through points waiting the needed
        for point in points[:-1]:
            self.setPosition(point)
            self.sendEvent('0 0 0')
            self.device.shell(f'sleep {wait}')

        # End swipe
        self.sendEvent('1 330 0')  # BTN_TOUCH Up
        self.sendEvent('0 0 0')  # SYN_REPORT


c = Client()
touch = AdbInput(c, 0)

# Touch
touch.tap((1000,600))
```

Comment: [/uiDevice/swipe](https://mrin9.github.io/OpenAPI-Viewer/#/load/https%3A%2F%2Fraw.githubusercontent.com%2Fdtmilano%2FCulebraTester2-public%2Fmaster%2Fopenapi.yaml) can send very precise swipes. Check [CulebraTester2-public](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public)

Comment: it doesn't seem to communicate source code :(

Comment: I didn't get what you mean, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Well I need to implement these swipes into a python code but CulebraTester2-public doesn't seems to share the code itself

Comment: Still don't get what you want to share...

Comment: Did you try the android's `input` command?

Comment: i found a simple solution using another input_swipe to block the first one. I'm still not understanding why the send event command isn't working unfortunately :(